# The annihilator numbers of $S/I$

Tags: combinatorics, commutative-algebra, monomial-ideals, simplicial-complex

> Let $S=K[x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}]$ and $I$ be a strongly stable ideal of $S$. 
>   Compute the annihilator numbers of $S/I$ with respect to the almost regular sequence 
>   $x_{n},x_{n-1},...,x_{1}$. (Herzog and Hibi, *Monomial Ideals*, Exercise 4.8.)

Note that a sequence $x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}$ is called *almost regular* if the length of $(0:_{M/{({x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{i-1})M}}}x_{i})$ is finite and the ideal $I$ is *strongly stable* if $x_{i}(u/x_{j})\in I$ for all monomials $u$ belong to $I$ and all $i<j$ such that $x_{j}$ divides $u$.
We denote by $A_{i-1}(y;M)$ the graded module $0:_{M/{({y_{1},y_{2},...,y_{i-1})M}}}$ $y_{i}$ and call the numbers $a_{ij}(y;M)=\dim_{K} A_{i}(y;M)_{j}$ if $i < n$ and
$\beta_{0j}(M)$ if $i=n$ the *annihilator numbers* of $M$ with respect to the sequence $y$.

Comment: Thank you for your question! It is good practice on this site to add a bit of information on the context your question came up in, and to share your own work on it. It's also fine if you state that you're completely lost -- the information is helpful for answerers to gauge their answer on. For more information on asking a good question on this site, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/43351).